# Template disambiguator needed with clang in member function template of non-template class but not with g++?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++

```
template <class T>
struct A {
  template <class X>
  void foo() {}
};

struct B {
  template <class T>
  void foo() {
    A<T>().foo<T>(); // no need of template disambiguator?
  }
};

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

g++-5.4 and -6.2 accept this code, but clang-3.8 doesn't and gives the following error message:

> main.cc:11:12: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'foo' as a
>   dependent template name

I think that there should be a `template`. And my question is : Is there any reason that g++ accept this code?

Comment: yes, that is a bug. it was fixed for non-member functions in g++-6.2. 
(with non member `void foo() { A<T>().foo<T>(); }` g++-6.2 will produce an error).